# Delete SQLite InMemoryDb in msTest

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, unit-testing

I have an MsTest project which has the following:

```
private MyDbContext _dbCtx;

private MyDbContext CreateSqlLiteDbCtx()
        {
            var dbConnection = new SqliteConnection()
            {
                ConnectionString = "Data Source=:memory:",
            };

            dbConnection.Open();
            var _contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                               .UseSqlite(dbConnection)
                               .Options;

            return new MyDbContext(_contextOptions);
        }



 [TestInitialize]
        public void InitTests()
        {
            _dbCtx= CreateSqlLiteDbCtx();
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
            _dbCtx?.Database.EnsureDeleted(); // Remove from memory
            _dbCtx?.Dispose();
        }

[TestMethod] 
public async Task MyTest() 
{   
  if (_dbCtx.Database.EnsureCreated())   
   {
       // run test            
   }   
   catch (Exception)   
   {
     throw;  
   } 
 }
```

My problem is that there's already data in my inmemory database that's bad. I'd like to find a way to clear out this database and have a fresh start. Re-running the unit tests with the `EnsureDeleted` doesn't seem to be working for me. How do I start over and clean out this db?

Comment: Create the context in each test.

Comment: @DanielA.White I tried that with EnsureDeleted and Dispose at the end of each test. There's still old data when the tests first run. I'm not getting a fresh set for each unit test.

Comment: What do you mean by _there's already data in my inmemory database_? As far as I can see, you're not seeding any data, only the `MyDbContext`